# Firebase NSInvalidArgumentException in Cocos2d-x Game - '-[__NSCFConstantString fira_UTF32Length]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Firebase (C++ edition) into our Cocos2d-x game, but I'm getting the runtime error:

2018-04-19 10:03:26.163854-0700 WordTurds-mobile[2328:2036998] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString fira_UTF32Length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1013a4a40'

This is occurring when initializing Firebase inside our AppController.mm's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, specifically this line is crashing:

```
firebaseApp = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions());
```

It might also be interesting that I tried using the Objective-C version of Firebase and saw the same exception when sending an Analytics screen view manually.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -ObjC to the Other Linker Flags fixes the issue.  I didn't have any ObjC in my project so I didn't think I needed the flag.